# Write a custom plugin for a bundler like parcel in a web app

Tags: node.js, plugins, web-applications, parceljs

I have my own `nodejs` web application which is using [Parcel 2](https://parceljs.org/) to bundle the resources.

```json
{
  "name": "acme-web-app",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "",
  "keywords": [],
  "license": "",
  "author": "",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "parcel build index.html",
    "dev": "parcel index.html --open",
    "start": "npm run build && npm run dev",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@parcel/packager-raw-url": "^2.6.0",
    "@parcel/transformer-sass": "^2.6.0",
    "@parcel/transformer-webmanifest": "^2.6.0",
    "parcel": "^2.6.0",
    "sass": "^1.52.2"
  }
}
```

All works fine - the js bundles end up in a dist folder.

I am contemplating whether it is possible to write a parcel [plug-in](https://parceljs.org/plugin-browser/) within this project is executed when the `build` script is run.

Is it possible - or does every reference need to go through npm channels via devDependencies?

I haven't figured a starting point for this - and have not been able to find what I am looking for on google so hopefully, the question makes sense.

**NOTE:** I have only really built web applications with `nodejs`.

Comment: Struggled to find the docs earlier. I suggest I should start here https://parceljs.org/plugin-system/overview/

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with the plugin / `build` script?

Comment: I was contemplating asking a different question which seemingly has already been asked on parcel's git issues - with no good responses.  Its just packaging up static files like the robots.txt etc - without bundling them.  Which has some plugins done for v2 - here - https://github.com/elwin013/parcel-reporter-static-files-copy

Comment: But for now - I just want to learn to write a plugin in parcel - just for experimentation.  So without creating a build/test setup for the extension - just going to hack something in my webapp project.